# Python Function fill in one argument at first, then the rest

Tags: python

I want to:
Pass a function around, making it receive one argument at first, and then the other later.
Here are the details:

```
def SuLQ(g, S, d):
    sigma = 0
    for i in S:
        sigma += g(d[i])
    if sigma <= len(S) and sigma >= 0:#required for DP
        return sigma + np.random.normal(loc = 0.0,scale = R)
    else:
        return 0


def sa_dir(wj, di):
    if np.dot(wj, di) <= 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0

whole_set = [i for i in xrange(48843)]#[n]

two_d_array, targ = predict_on_b()
w0 = [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,
-1,  0,  0,  -1,  0,  0,  0,  -1,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  -1,  0,  0,  0,  0,
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  -1,
0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0]

num_mis_vecs = SuLQ(sa_dir(wj = w0,), whole_set, two_d_array)
```

In the line:

```
num_mis_vecs = SuLQ(sa_dir(wj = w0,), whole_set, two_d_array)
```

I passed the function sa_dir as an argument to SuLQ, while giving sa_dir one argument wj (the direction vector).

the other argument for sa_dir is given in the function(where g is another name for sa_dir(wj,di) with argument wj already fixed)

```
SuLQ(g, S, d)
```

when executing

```
sigma += g(d[i])
```

But it seems that python does not allow this. Here is the error i got.

```
TypeError: sa_dir() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I don't want to hard-code wj into sa_dir because I want to change wj later.
Anyone has got suggestions? Thanks in advance.

(Just in case you are interested, I am re-implementing a paper's framework using python.)
(http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.126.209&rep=rep1&type=pdf)

Comment: sounds like you want to do partial function application -- check out `functools.partial()`, docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html)

Comment: `SuLQ(lambda di: sa_dir(w0, di), whole_set, two_d_array)`.

Comment: Thank you for  these comments! They work well. I like the lambda expression approach because it makes clear what happened during the application process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is the `functools.partial` function, which takes one function and part of the arguments and then applies them later with all added arguments:

```
from functools import partial

num_mis_vecs = SuLQ(partial(sa_dir, wj = w0), whole_set, two_d_array)
```